# Any way to make a simple page link in Adobe Acrobat?

Tags: pdf, adobe, acrobat

So I am using Adobe Acrobat Pro DC and want to create a link to another page in the PDF. Is there any way to make a simple "go to page X" link without having to scroll though hundreds of pages to get the page manually? I want to be able to create a link to go to a page number with Inherent Zoom, but so far the only way I have found to do so is to create link, scroll all the way down to the page, and then edit the link after the fact. Surely there is an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The link dialog is modal but the destination dialog box is non-modal. Just draw out the link, select "Go to a page view", hit the "Next" button. When the "Create go to view" dialog pops up, type in the page number you want in the main toolbar, set the zoom you want then hit Set Link.